# Extending Euclidean Valuation (algebra chapter 0)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, euclidean-domain

Exercise 3.2.15 in Aluffi's Algebra: Chapter 0 goes as follows:

> Given a Euclidean Domain $R$ with valuation $v$, show that there exists a Euclidean valuation $\overline{v}$ on $R$ such that $\overline{v}(ab) \geq \overline{v}(b)$ for all $a, b \in R$.

He then goes on to give a hint as to what the valuation should be, namely, $\overline{v}(a)$ is the minimum of $v(ab)$ across all $b \in R$. I've shown that this valuation satisfies the required property, but I'm having a little trouble showing that $\overline{v}$ is in fact Euclidean. Aluffi suggests writing arbitrary $a, b$ as $a = qb + r$, with $v(r) < v(b)$, assume that $\overline{v}(r) \geq \overline{v}(b)$, and reach a contradiction from this, but I haven't been able to do so. I feel like if I knew what form the contradiction should take I should be able to reach it, but more extensive or alternative solutions are more than welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Relatively old question, but since it was never answered and I wanted to verify my own answer here it goes (for whoever stumbles upon it):

Define everything as Aluffi does in his hint. Let $k \in R$ be the element that minimizes $\tilde{v}(b)$; i.e. $\tilde{v}(b) = v(bk)$. Since $R$ is a Euclidean Domain, then for $a$ and $bk$ there are $q_1, r_1 \in R$ such that:
$$a=bkq_1 + r_1$$
with $v(r_1) < v(bk)$ (since $a \nmid b$).

Now, by the definition we gave of $k$, $v(r_1) < v(bk) \leq v(b)$, so $v(r_1) < v(b)$. This implies we can define $kq_1 = q_2$ and write:
$$a=bq_2 + r_1$$
with $v(r_1) < v(b)$. Since we know that $v(r)$ is minimal, then $v(r) \leq v(r_1) < v(bk)$. Which, by the definition of $\tilde{v}$, implies $\tilde{v}(r) < \tilde{v}(b)$; contradicting our assumption. Hence, $\tilde{v}$ defines a Euclidean valuation on $R$.

Comment: Nice username.  You should be more careful when allowing for the possibility that the remainder may be $0$: the function $v$ is not defined at $0$.  The exercise in Aluffi is for *nonzero* $a$ and $b$ (which the OP forgot to include), but it's still possible to have a remainder of $0$. See Theorem 2.1 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ringtheory/euclideanrk.pdf.

Comment: @KCd Slowly going through Aluffi's text, so it seemed fitting lol. Thanks for the warning, trivial as that case may be it's true it needs to be addressed. Also thanks for that document, I think I'll be finding it pretty useful in the near future!